# WiX 3.11.1 Burn bootstrapper fails to elevate

Tags: installation, wix, windows-10, windows-installer, wix3.11

We have a setup built with WiX 3.11.1 and if that exe is not launched with elevated privileges (aka "Run as Administrator"), then we are trying to trigger a new process programmatically with verb as **"runas"** and filename as the location from where the main exe was launched (C:\Users\loggedin_username\AppData\Local\Temp{GUID}.cr\setup_name.exe)

But the new triggered process exits suddenly by creating new log file in temp directory with below messages:

- Error 0x80070006: Failed to seek to start of file.
- Error 0x80070006: Failed to initialize engine section.
- Error 0x80070006: Failed to initialize engine state.

If we do the same with WiX 3.10.2 (triggering a new process with elevated permissions programmatically) then it creates a new process and works fine.

I guess, from WiX 3.11.1 we can't launch same exe with elevated permissions. Not sure if WiX team has made any significant changes related to security. Is this a known issues in WiX 3.11.1 ?

All I want to achieve is to add/modify key values of installed setup registry entry in HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall path. On Windows 10 and above, only Administrators can have full access to HKLM path.

If the WiX setups are launched with "Run as Administrator" option everything works fine but if user has not launched with that option, I want to programmatically launch with elevated permissions to access HKLM path but with WiX 3.11.1 it is failing.

Any suggestions on how to achieve ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn doesn't support elevated bootstrapper applications. To write to per-machine locations like `HKLM`, do so in a package.